# Hellosign multiple signers emails not received

Tags: php, symfony, hellosign-api

I'm working on a Hello sign project where I am sending data to a template and sending it to multiple clients at the same time. But when I add multiple signers the mails are not received from the emails I add there. I tried with 2 signers.

This is how I added it in the code. Email received with a single singer, but not with two.

```
$request->setSigner('Client', 'aaa@bbb.ccc', 'AA');
$request->setSigner('Client', 'bbb@ccc.ddd', 'BBB');
```

What could be the issue in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each signer role can only have one [signer assigned to it](https://app.hellosign.com/api/templatesAndApiWalkthrough#TemplateSetup), so you'll need to update the template itself to differentiate the two signer roles for 'Client'.

Something like 'Client1' and 'Client2' would do the trick.

Then once the template's updated, pass in

```
$request->setSigner('Client1', 'aaa@bbb.ccc', 'AA');
$request->setSigner('Client2', 'bbb@ccc.ddd', 'BB');
```

This assumes that your document has two 'Clients' signing it. If your document has one signer and is signed by one 'Client', and each 'Client' signs their own individual document, then you'll need to create individual signature requests for each signer.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for the answer.